# Add links to navigation based on INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a project that has a number of apps. These apps translate into modules that perform different functions for the end user.

Now each deployment of the project may have certain apps enabled or disabled.

What I'd like to achieve is a navigation list of links that only displays links for apps that are in INSTALLED_APPS.

For example deployment 1 has App1 and App2 listed in INSTALLED_APPS so would have a navigation something like this:

- Link to App1's view
- Link to App2's view

And deployment 2 has App2 and App3 installed so should show a navigation something like this:

- Link to App2's view
- Link to App3's view

Without having a navigation defined in a base template and editing it for each deployment, I can't see a way of doing this. Even by using `{ block.super }`, this seems to not allow 2 apps to be installed as each child template would append to the parent.

Comment: Does each app only have 1 view? Or do you have have a homepage for each one? What about apps that don't have views? For example database migrations (South), admin skins, css/js compressors, etc.

Comment: @j_syk I only want this for my apps (not admin, South etc) and each one will have a homepage, that's the only thing I want a link to really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strictly from the top of my head, so it may not be the "best" or most appropriate way.

First, if you're going to rely on `INSTALLED_APPS` you should actually implement something along the lines of:

```
MY_INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'app1',
   'app2',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
   # other installed apps
) + MY_INSTALLED_APPS
```

Then, instead of having to figure out which of the items in `INSTALLED_APPS` are yours and which are third-party, you just use `MY_INSTALLED_APPS` instead for things like building your menus.

Second, in Django, apps aren't tied to views in any meaningful way. There's no concept of a "default" view, and you can't simply link to an app. However, you can some what achieve this idea through the use of namespaces and a convention for view naming, specifically, all your apps will at least have a urlpattern named "index", for example.

Then, in your urls.py you create urlpatterns like:

```
url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls', namespace='app1', app_name='app1'),
url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls', namespace='app2', app_name='app2'),
# etc
```

In each app, you create a urls.py that has at least one urlpattern:

```
url(r'^$', some_view, name='index'),
```

This means that the going to `/app1/` in your browser would then load `some_view` and you can reference this view in your code with a name like: `app1:index`.

The tricky part is using this in your templates. Django 1.5 will add the ability to use context variables in the `{% url %)` tag for the view name. As of Django 1.3, you can use this behavior as well via `{% load url from future %}`. However, even that only gets you part-way to what you need.

In your template, you'll need to loop through the values of `MY_INSTALLED_APPS` and construct the links. The following *should* work in Django 1.3-1.4 via `{% load url from future %}` or Django 1.5:

```
{% for app in apps %}
    <a href="{% url app|add:":index" %}">{{ app }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The other way to accomplish this is with a template filter, which is your only option in Django <1.3, and may still be preferable in later versions. Something like:

```
@register.filter
def default_url_for_app(app):
    return reverse(app+':index')
```

And, in your template:

```
{% for app in apps %}
    <a href="{{ app|default_url_for_app }}">{{ app }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely a very good idea, and I've taken away some good tips from this (and for that I'm accepting your answer) but I've decided to use the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584292/autodiscover-widgets-for-django-apps-registered-in-settins-py), and create "widgets". One widget for each app being a snippet of HTML to add a navigation link to an URLconf definition of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple import your settings.py file and iterate over the INSTALLED_APPS list.

```
from django.conf import settings
for installed_app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
```

But I'm also in doubt if this is a smart decision to implement your application as such.

Comment: Still going to need some sort of dictionary with urls for each app and probably a whitelist of which apps to use.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines too, but again that only gives you the path to the app, not sure how you could get the urls from that.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want here is some kind of app registration system. That is, for each app that's loaded (ie included in INSTALLED_APPS), register its homepage with the list of links.

Rather than doing all this automatically, I would follow the example of the admin application and get each app to call a register function on first load. You could do this in the models.py, for example, since you know that will be imported by Django on startup. The register function would take the app name and the url and build a dictionary which could then be passed to each template via a context processor.